# Thumbnail images chopped off but not cropped to exact dimensions

Tags: media, media-settings

In Media Settings I have Thumbnail sizes set to width and height of 150 and "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)" is *not* checked.

Since the checkbox is not checked, shouldn't the entire image be retained (since thumbnails are supposedly proportional)? However, it is not (see below). Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Was that image uploaded before, or after you changed the setting? Media settings are only applied to uploads, WordPress can't go back and change images that have already been uploaded

Comment: Before. I deleted the image and re-uploaded it and it looks as it should now. Thanks!

Comment: There's the regenerate thumbnails plugin that can do that for you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tom's comments I better understand the issue. There are a number of solutions:

- re-upload the image *after* applying new media settings
- Regenerate the thumbnails with the "Regenerate Thumbnails" plugin or with wp-cli's *wp media regenerate*.